# Add quote to every item in a Python List

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

I have the following Python list from BeautifulSoup (for example):

```
[Basketball, Ipad Pro, Macbook Pro, Racket]
```

I need to add quote to every item in the list, as shown below:

```
['Basketball', 'Ipad Pro', 'Macbook Pro', 'Racket']
```

I have tried several methods, but not getting the right result.

### The actual script:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

products =[]
prices = []
for page in range(1,9):
    url = 'https://www.lelong.com.my/catalog/all/list?TheKeyword=ipad+pro&D='+str(page)
    r = requests.get(url)
    prices.extend([price.find('b') for price in soup.find_all('span',{'class':'price pull-right'})])
    products.extend([title.find('b') for title in soup.find_all('div',{'class':'summary'})])
```

For the products, I got the list as shown above.

Comment: show us your code

Comment: How you building that *string* in the first place? It's generally a good idea to produce a valid list rather than a string that looks vaguely like the representation of a list.

Comment: how can `[Basketball, Ipad Pro, Macbook Pro, Racket]` be a list ?

Comment: The first list isn't valid Python, what is your actual input & expected output?

Comment: added the actual code

Comment: test_list = "person,bicycle,car,motorcycle,airplane,bus",print(test_list.split(','))

Answer (score 3):

Your list `[Basketball, Ipad Pro, Macbook Pro, Racket]` is not valid `list` in python. You may try to Add quote to every item in a Python List this way:

```
arr = ['Basketball', 'Ipad Pro', 'Macbook Pro', 'Racket']
A = []
for x in arr:
    A.append("'" + x + "'")
print(A)
# output : 
# A = ["'Basketball'", "'Ipad Pro'", "'Macbook Pro'", "'Racket'"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider as string:
test_list = "Basketball, Ipad Pro, Macbook Pro, Racket"
print(test_list.split(','))